# When reading network sockets, how long will the read syscall return short counts?

Tags: linux, sockets

I want to know the range, like dozens of clocks, thousands of clocks...etc.
I am using a telnet protocol.

I already check the man page about read and stackoverflow

Comment: There's no defined range, unless you set a timeout yourself using setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO).

Comment: Thank you. I fond the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62859/default-value-for-so-rcvtimeo-option-on-solaris